# Android Adoptable Storage - find out if internal SD is mounted

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdcard, android-internal-storage

When thinking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117508/android-adoptable-storage-get-free-space) question I asked, I wondered: Is there really no way of finding out if a [adopted SD](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable.html) is present?
With a Motorola G3 there were two paths returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` when an external SD was present, but only one (the emulated one, thats always present) when formatting the SD as internal. Other devices seem to behave similar.

So, if I am looking to know if there is a internal SD present, where would I need to look? Is there anything (non manufacturer specific) provided, so e.g. I could check, if the user expects to use the internal emulated `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` because he has mounted a internal SD?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?